# Inconsistent reputation shown in Android app when hitting the rep cap

Tags: bug, android-app, achievements-dialog

When hitting the rep cap, the next day, the achievements tab in the Android app doesn't show consistent reputation points for the days before. A picture is worth thousand words:

[image]

Compare to what it shows from the web site:

[image]